# Pandas, converting columns to integer, invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

.dtypes shows the "Amount" column is by default an object

So I tried this,

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(int)
```

I got this error,

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,448.91'
```

Comment: In your own words, given that `'3,448.91'` appears in the column, what do you think should be the `int` result for that? Why? In your own words, what does `int` mean?

Comment: It's a function that converts a value to an integer

Comment: In your own words, what is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your column contains a comma(`,`). First replace that with empty string, then convert the type to `int`.

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
```

If you want to round off the values and convert to `int`, do this:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float).round().astype(int)
```

Comment: This will not fix the problem, as `'3448.91'` still cannot be converted to integer. There are two things OP could possibly want: to convert to `float` instead, or to round or truncate the value to an integer according to some rule. The question should not be answered until that is resolved.

Comment: I downvoted, because I knew you would still get that error.

Comment: @Pythonaccount Try the answer now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please check my updated answer. I've handled both the cases you pointed out.

Comment: @Mayank Porwal I must be doing something really stupid.  First first line above errors as "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!". However if I instead create a new column instead of overwriting Amount, df['New_Amount'] = .... It works fine.

Comment: @Pythonaccount That's weird. You can anyway first create `New_Amount` and drop `Amount` column and then rename `New_Amount` to `Amount`.